# jar file causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, jar, executable-jar

I created a java project in eclipse and then i generated a runnable jar out of it. the java project has a class named DrivingModule. the jar file was imported in to an android 
project. but the problem is, when i run the android project the app crash as long as i use the class DrivingModule and i receive the following error

```
*06-01 11:38:10.481: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available*
```

and if i commented out the class DrivingModule, the App works normall. i referred to some questions but mainely they were explaining how to generate the jar and how to build the path, but i could not find any post about how to solve the error i am receiving.

why that class causes the App to crash and throw such error?

**update**

after refering to the answer of  Bhaumik Thakkar the App did nt work until I checked the box of the added jar as shown in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put your jars in your -> jdk -> lib -> ext and then try again..

Comment: i dont have ext folder, should i create it?

Comment: oops sorry!! Please go through the below hierarchy and put into it.
(find the below hierarchy in your program files folder)

 **jdk** ->

     **jre** ->
          **lib** ->
               **ext** ->

Comment: actually when i trie your answer the App worked normally, but when i created a new workspace and imported the same App and set the same jar file, i received the same error again..any suggestions

Comment: have you created jar again properly? and make your you're using the same java version in which you have kept the jars...

Comment: would you please have a look at the update. and can u please let meknow why without checking the box of the added jar the App does not work? what does it mean to check the box or does not check it

Comment: if u'll check than n than only it will be added in your projects build path.